# How launch of certain TestSuite using the parameter in jUnit?

Tags: java, junit

I have test classes which uses other test classes. It is necessary to run these classes depending on the transferred parameter in Jenkins. (For example: if jenkins get parameter testOne then start testsuite testOne. If jenkins get parameter testOther then start testsuite testOther and so on)

How can I implement this in jUnit?

This is an example of one of the test suites:

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({UserLogin.class,
        ExampleTests.class
        }
)
public class FirstTest {
```

Comment: What do you mean with "depending on the transferred parameter"? Can you please provide some more information.

Comment: @StefanBirkner For example: if jenkins get parameter FirstTest then start testsuite FirstTest. If jenkins get parameter testOther then start testsuite testOther and so on

Comment: Are you using a build tool like Ant, Gradle or Maven?

Comment: @StefanBirkner I use Maven.

Comment: Please have a look at Atul's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like that using [junit test categories](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/experimental/categories/Categories.html). For example, for running integration tests, you can configure a separate annotation for the tests.

Maven [supports](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html) test categories.

Does it solve your problem or is the jenkins input parameter critical? If it is a jenkins parameter, I believe it is some environment/build configuration and you can customize your build (maven tests to be run) as per the the environment or build job.